Why MgB2 is superconductor and AlB2 not?
MgB2 and AlB2 crystallize in a hexagonal system in the structure shown below. The lattice constants c are 0.352 and 0.325 nm, respectively. MgB2 is a superconductor and AlB2 is a semiconductor. What is the reason for the difference in the electrical properties of these two materials?


Seems MgB2 is unique https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnesium_diboride

yes, but why does this property depend on a lattice constant c?

One could say it depends on plenty of things. One could say it depends on just one - the element between boron layers, and this dependence is rather stringent.

Neon and copper have the same crystal structure. Why is one a conductor and the other isn't?

MgB2 and AlB2 share a structure but differ in electrical properties due to their electronic band structures. In MgB2, a slight overlap between valence and conduction bands allows for easy electron flow, making it a superconductor. AlB2's wider band gap hinders electron movement, making it a semiconductor.  Essentially, MgB2's band structure facilitates superconductivity, whereas AlB2's limits conduction.

References please for the data behind the band gap argument.

@IanBush right. Who in the world is upvoting this?

Superconductors conduct electricity despite the energy gap. There is no direct relation like conductivity=zero gap.

Please provide references.

I feel like this statement is not generally true. I would like to see some references
